# Create inApp purchase products automatically from php server?

Tags: php, in-app-purchase, itunes

Is there any way to create iTunes inApp purchase product automatically from php server using any kind of available APIs?

I just want any alternate way rather than that manual process of creation of inApp purchase products through iTunes.